# Because the sine function is an odd function, for a negative number u, sin2u= -2sinucosu

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm not sure I get this.

Because the sine function is an odd function, for
a negative number u, sin2u= -2sinucosu

Is it true or false and why?

Comment: Angle-sum identities.

Comment: The compound angle formula for $\sin()$ can be given by $\sin (2 \theta) = 2 \sin (\theta) \cos(\theta)$, regardless of the **sign** of $\theta$.

Comment: $\sin 2u=2 \sin u \cos u$; $\sin -x=-\sin x$

Comment: if $u$ is negative, $2u$ is also negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False. $$\sin 2u = 2\sin u\cos u$$ is an identity, true for any $u$. If $u<0$, write $u=-x$ where $x>0$. Then $$\sin 2u = \sin(-2x) = -\sin(2x) = -2\sin x\cos x = -2\sin(-u)\cos(-u) = 2\sin u\cos u$$
where the second and final steps follow since $\sin$ is odd and $\cos$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

It is false. The formula
$$
\sin (2u) = 2 \sin u \cos u
$$

holds for all $u \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $\underline{\bf\text{Sum of Two Angles}}$ formula:

$$
\sin{(a+b)}=\sin{(a)}\cos{(b)}+\sin{(b)}\cos{(a)}\text{.}
$$

Let $a=b=-\phi\ni(\phi\in\mathbb{R}\land\phi\geq0)$, and let’s see what happens.

$$
\begin{align}
\sin{(-2\phi)}&=2\sin{(-\phi)}\cos{(-\phi)}\\
-\sin{(2\phi)}&=-2\sin{(\phi)}\cos{(\phi)}\\
\sin{(2\phi)}&=2\sin{(\phi)}\cos{(\phi)}
\end{align}
$$

As you can see, this had no effect.

Another way to think about it is using the fact that $\sin{x}$ is odd and $\cos{x}$ is even, and the fact that an odd function multiplied with an even function produces an odd function as its product.

$$
\begin{align}
\sin{(2\phi)}&=2\sin{(\phi)}\cos{(\phi)}\\
(\text{odd})&=(\text{odd})(\text{even})=(\text{odd})
\end{align}
$$

Since it boils down to $(\text{odd})=(\text{odd})$, pulling a $\,-1$ through each odd function will just divide out of the equation.